Pepper Robot: Animation works in Choregraphe but not when I package it and send to Pepper Robot
I've been working with Pepper Robot and wanted to add a couple of the Entertainment animations to it, so when I ask if it knows how to vacuum it will say "Sure, let me demonstrate" and then perform the animation.
I created a dialog box with some outputs so if I ask "Do you know how to vacuum" it will use the vacuum output which is linked to the animation.  It works perfectly when connected to Pepper in Choregraphe but as soon as I package it and send it to Pepper and disconnect.  I can ask it the question, it will respond but it doesn't perform the animation.
I've tried using a python script and renaming the box.xar file for that animation to vacuum.xar and placing it in a subfolder called animations in the project folder on pepper and using python script to call it but it says I'm not using the correct path syntax.  I've tried using "projectname/animations/vacuum.xar" and "animations/vacuum.xar" but neither work.
Am I missing something?  I've even tried adding Delays and a Init & Reset script in the mix but still it won't perform the animation unless I'm connected to the robot in Choregraphe.
Any help would be gratefully appreciated, has any body managed this?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Turns out I needed to create an HTML folder in the root of my project and drop the vacuum.ogg file in that folder.
